# Online survey which can filter results based on demographic questions

Tags: web-apps, survey

I would like to know if there are any online survey systems which allow for the results to be easily filtered based on a few demographic questions we will have.

- Our needs in terms of survey functionality are basic: mostly checkboxes and radio buttons, with a few "Other: " options on some questions
- We will have at most three questions which we would like to filter results by: age, gender and type of member association
- Most survey systems will export the results, from which we could manually filter them. The ideal response would allow us to specify those few demographic questions as the filtering keys and then allow us to interactively view the results for different filter combinations

Answer (score 2):

I do not have personal experience based on this topic but however,I hope following survey will help you to achieve what you want to.

1. [SurveyMonkey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/)- Based on your requirement here are some few details I found on the website.
   [image: View Collector Status]

[image: Demographics As Shown on Analyze Results page]
[image: Demographics As Shown in Exported Results]

Comment: From [this page](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Analyzing-Results-from-SurveyMonkey-Audience-Projects) it doesn't look like they will do that based on demographic questions you can specify.

Answer (score 0):

[Surveypal](http://surveypal.com) offers a way to filter results based on the answers given by respondents. The filtering can be based on one or multiple conditions as described on [support pages](http://support.surveypal.com/en/analysis-results/creating-filters/). Even though Surveypal doesn't support demographic questions as separate elements, they can easily be generated manually as check boxes etc.

For example you could filter by only the respondents who are of *age 20-25* in case you have such an option on your one selection element asking for respondent age. You can also combine these filters and match only partials of for example text fields such as *city contains "New "*

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Survata](http://survata.com)? I've run a few small surveys with them, and they deliver both a csv, as well as a nice web view of that results that include very easy segmenting into all the criteria you mention.